# Using CSS, is there a way to change the opacity of an SVG's <filter> element?

Tags: css, svg

I have this SVG path that changes its color on `hover`.  However, I want its drop-shadow which I created using a `filter` element to disappear on `hover` too.  Is there a way to do this in CSS?  I tried using `fill-opacity` -- it worked on the `rect` element, but not on the `filter` element.

Here's the fiddle  with the shadow still visible: http://jsfiddle.net/4d6j4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can animate flood-opacity property of feFlood element by css.

http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/SwHDR/

svg structure:

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="90" height="90"/>
    <defs>
        <filter id="f4" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feOffset dx="20" dy="20" result="offOut"/>
            <feFlood/>
            <feComposite operator="in" in2="offOut"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

css:

```
feFlood{
    flood-color: navy;
}
rect{
    filter:url(#f4);
    fill:aqua;
    stroke:green;
    stroke-width:2;
}
rect,feFlood{
    transition:all 2s;
}
rect:hover{
    fill:blue;
}
rect:hover+defs feFlood{
    flood-opacity:0;
}
```

for chrome:
Chrome fails to find feFlood element by selector at inline svg. So we need to rewrite css selector by :nth-child pseudo class like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/djMq8/1/

```
filter#f4>:nth-child(2){
    flood-color: navy;
}
rect{
    filter:url(#f4);
    fill:aqua;
    stroke:green;
    stroke-width:2;
}
rect,filter#f4>:nth-child(2){
    transition:all 2s;
}
rect:hover{
    fill:blue;
}
rect:hover+defs>filter#f4>:nth-child(2){
    flood-opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting that it only works in FireFox.  Do you know how this can work on webkit browsers like Chrome?

Comment: Oh! When I tested this code by stand alone svg file, this code works fine on Chrome too. But on using inline svg like jsFiddle, doesn't work... Thank you ayjay. The code is here http://www.h2.dion.ne.jp/~defghi/fadingShadow.svg

Comment: The bug you see in Chrome has to do with selectors on camelcased elements - see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286677.

Comment: In case it helps others, here is more documentation about animating SVG using CSS: [SVG Presentation Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#presentation_attributes), [The `<filter>` Element](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterElement), [SVG's styling properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-SVGTiny12-20081222/styling.html)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove the shadow by removing the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) altogether in CSS:

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6AuK8/)***

```css
svg rect:hover
{
    fill: blue;
    filter: none;
}
```

Then, after some finagling, I was able to successfully transition the drop shadow and the fill color.  I had to put the shadow on `svg` instead of the `svg rect` with separate `:hover` styles as well:

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WWDgE/)***

**HTML**

```html
<svg>
    <rect width="90" height="90" />
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```css
svg
{
    transition: all 2s;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 10px black);
       -moz-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 10px black);
            filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 10px black);
}
svg rect 
{
    transition: all 2s;

    fill: aqua;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
svg:hover 
{
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0);
       -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0);
            filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0);
}
svg:hover rect 
{
    fill: blue;
}
```

***One caveat seems to be that you have to use `transition: all` vs `transition: filter`.***

Also, the CSS [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property is not fully cross-browser compatible either.

Here's the current [Browser Compatiblity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) as of 2014.07.21:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know that  an svg `filter` could be a CSS attribute.  I played around with it, but coudln't make it transition smoothly.  Is `transition` possible with the `filter` attribute?

Comment: Thanks, and It works great on Webkit!  Though, FireFox doesn't seem to understand `filter: drop-shadow` effects currently.

Comment: @ayjay - You would be correct, I added MDN's Browser Compatibility charts to the answer.