# Is it possible to animate the opacity of a SVG filter with CSS code?

Tags: html, css, button, svg, hover

I have an svg image that works as a button. As you hover over the button the svg fill changes to a different color, but I also wish the inner shadow filter I created to appear as well. That is, to change from 0% opacity to 100%.

I was able to change the fill color with css transitions. Is it possible to change the opacity of the filter too with css?

Here's the SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1"  id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="36.25px" height="23px" viewBox="5 -5 36.25 23" enable-background="new 0 0 36.25 23" xml:space="preserve">

<!--Definiciones del Filtro-->
<filter id="sombra" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
<feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
<feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
</feComponentTransfer>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
<feOffset dx="-1" dy="-1" result="offsetblur"/>
<feFlood flood-color="rgb(20, 0, 0)" result="color"/>
<feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
<feMergeNode />
</feMerge>
</filter> 

<g filter="url(#sombra)">
<polygon points="23.671,8.625 23.671,4.657 21.786,4.657 21.786,7.513 18.255,5.433 18.194,5.398 18.058,5.398 
4.724,13.249 5.502,14.57 7.862,13.179 7.862,18.343 9.396,18.343 9.396,12.276 18.128,7.138 26.854,12.276 26.854,18.343 
28.388,18.343 28.388,13.179 30.75,14.57 31.526,13.249   "/>

<rect x="15.289" y="11.553" width="2.44" height="2.444"/>
<rect x="18.523" y="11.553" width="2.438" height="2.444"/>
<rect x="15.289" y="14.656" width="2.44" height="2.439"/>
<rect x="18.523" y="14.656" width="2.438" height="2.439"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#Capa_1{
fill:#FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: fill 0.3s;
}

#Capa_1:hover{
fill:#8A653B;
}
```

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: like this ? [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/azYNYb)

Comment: No, not really. The idea is to begin with the white image, with inner shadow being invisible. Then, as you hover over the button both the color and the filter should become visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching somebody had already answered this question.

Here's the workaround:
[Using CSS, is there a way to change the opacity of an SVG's <filter> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872322/using-css-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-opacity-of-an-svgs-filter-element)

It works around pretty well on the current versions of Firefox and Chrome. SVG animations don't seem to work well in IE though, but the filter opacity did change however.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Yes** [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) has a working draft of the **animatable filter**.

**but** [not a lot of support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) is currently available :(

And on svg elements it only works in firefox.

Here is a fiddle for the fire fox users: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyfmkntr/)

Applying an svg filter: `filter: url(#filterid)`
Applying an svg opacity filter: `filter: opacity(50%);`
And combined: `filter: url(#filterid) opacity(50%);`

Comment: Really? Only for firefox? :/ that´s lame. The fiddle looks exactly like what I tried, with no results on Chrome nor IE. Isn't there any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I also noticed that by adding the 'opacity' line in the filter, you don't modify the opacity of the filter but on the contrary add and modify an opacity filter by itself.

Comment: yh you probably have to include the opacity in the custom filter (if that's possible):
But even filters on svg is pretty experimental so your a bit ahead of time with doing this kind of thing in web browsers.

Comment: I didn't downvote Persijn. Somebody else did, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @GabrielLeni it was just a general comment. I'll add tags so there is no confusion :P